# how to translate or move QGraphicsView by mouse drag?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

what I did:

```py
class PDFView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__
        #somecode...

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if self.itemAt(event.pos()) is None:
            self.begin_drag=True
            self.begin_drag_pos=event.pos()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if self.begin_drag and self.begin_drag_pos is not None:
            delta = self.begin_drag_pos - event.pos()
            old_center = QPointF(
                (self.mapToScene(self.pos()).x() + self.width()) / 2,
                (self.mapToScene(self.pos()).y() + self.height()) / 2
            )
            self.centerOn(old_center+delta)
            self.update()

        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
        pass

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if self.begin_drag:
            self.begin_drag=False
            self.begin_drag_pos=None

        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

what I get: when I dragup , the scroll bar goes down, it's ok, but it will go up when next time I dragup.
[image]

I tried: translate,move, all failed.

how to translate or move QGraphicsView by mouse drag?

what's the problem with my code?

Comment: The problem will be clear if you look the documentation, as for solution remove code under `delta` and try: `self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.verticalScrollBar().value() + delta.y())`

Comment: @Artt thanks, but your solution not work well, the scroll bar move too fast  that I can't control

Comment: I solved this , using translate is ok , just to slow down it : `self.translate(delta.x()/10,delta.y()/10)`

Comment: Have you considered to use `self.setDragMode(self.ScrollHandDrag)` in the `__init__` instead?

Comment: thank you every much , this is exactly what I want!